# calling a parent UIViewController method from a child UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a Parent UIViewController, which opens a child UIViewController:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myChildView") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I press a Button in the ChildView which should close the the ChildView and call a method in the Parent View:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
CALL PARENTS METHOD  ??????
```

How to do that ? 
I found a good answer ([Link to good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427977/call-parentcontroller-method-from-childcontroller-in-swift)), but I am not sure if this is the best practice with UIViewControllers. Can someone help ?

Comment: The delegation pattern in your link is the correct way to do it, and it works just fine when you use ViewControllers.

The only time it doesn't work is when you're using Segues, but even then it's an extra two or three lines of code to get it to work. See the section title "Adding prepareForSegue" here: http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/01/swift-swift-using-segues-and-delegates-in-navigation-controllers-part-1-the-template/

Comment: Can u check my answer

Comment: Simplest way is found at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28476319/1953178

Comment: take a look here:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61596926/8160252)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One easy way to achieve this you can use `NSNotificationCenter` for that.

In your `ParentViewController` add this into `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("refresh:")), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"), object: nil)
}
```

After that add this function in `ParentViewController` which will get called when you dismiss your `ChildViewController`:

```
func refreshList(notification: NSNotification){

    print("parent method is called")
}
```

and into your `ChildViewController` add this code where you dismissing your child view:

```
 @IBAction func btnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"), object: nil)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now when you dismiss child view `refreshList` method will be call.

Answer (score 5):

Add a weak property to the child view controller that should contain a reference to the parent view controller

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
weak var parentViewController: UIViewController?
....
}
```

Then in your code (I'm assuming it's inside your parent view controller),

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myChildView") as! ChildViewController
vc.parentViewController = self
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And, as vomako said, call the parent's method before dismissing your child view controller.

```
parentViewController.someMethod()
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Or, you can also call the method in the completion paramter of dismissViewControllerAnimated, where it will be run *after* you child view controller dismisses:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
    parentViewController.someMethod()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping : theoretically this looks good, but I have problems practically :-). I get the error : Cannot assign to 'parentViewController' in vc. Second:

Comment: Did you cast the view controller as UIViewController or as a sublass of your UIViewController such as UIViewController? You have to subclass it if you want to have your additional properties. let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myChildView") as! **ChildViewController**

Answer (score 1):

Something that I've noticed in your question: Do not call a method (the parent method in your case) after dismissing the view controller. Dismissing the view controller will cause it to be deallocated. Later commands may not be executed.

The link that you've included in your question points to a good answer. In your case, I would use delegation. Call the delegation method in the parent view controller before you dismiss the child view controller.

Here is an excellent [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers/9736559#9736559).

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried to implement the solution in the good link, but I am facing a problem. With UIViewController I cant set the delegate ( child.delegate = self ). I mean I can't : vc.delegate=self.

Comment: Hello, it should work. What error message do you get?

Comment: 'UIViewController' does not have a member named 'delegate'

Comment: Make sure to include a property `delegate` in the header file (.h) of your child view controller (see the tutorial link I provided under `Passing Data Back`)

Answer (score 1):

```
protocol SampleProtocol 
{
    func someMethod()
}   


class parentViewController: SampleProtocol 
{
    // Conforming to SampleProtocol
    func someMethod() {
    }
}

 class ChildViewController
    {
        var delegate:SampleProtocol?
    }

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    delegate?.someMethod()
```