# swift 3 call function from parent ViewController

Tags: ios, class, swift3, protocols, uicontainerview

I have a ViewController, this view container has a class which creates 2 container views, and adds a table to the first container and a HashtagPicker for the second.

The hashTagPicker has a function which is called whenever a change to the selected hashTags happens.

**question**: i want to call a update table function whenever a tag is changed. How can i call a function from the hashtagclass which is defined in the class that contains the containers?

Comment: Means you have vc A that contains vc B and vc C, in vc B you do something and after that you want vc C to update it's table view?

Comment: The usual way is to pass a reference (protocol / delegate pattern) or callback closure from the parent to the child controller.

Comment: @Tj3n yes, exactly. vc B says new hashTags have been set, now tell vc A to tell vc B do call updateTable for example

Comment: @vadian can you show some example code as the answer?

Comment: Do you familiar with protocol/delegate? You can just use vc C to tell vc A that it have selected hashtag, and vc A can call directly vc B's update table since its vc A's child vc

Comment: @JochenÖsterreicher This kind of question is asked quite often on SO. There are lots of related questions and answers.

Comment: Use delegate or notifications/observer design patterns. As @vadian said is a typical beginner question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally like the delegate approach over notifications - the latter solution almost always leads to confusing architecture. Sadly, the example for the delegate approach, which is also the accepted answer, is even worse - it basically opens an opportunity for memory leaks. I'll explain. In the accepted solution, `ParentView` is holding a strong reference to `HashtagPicker` and, in turn, `HastagPicker` is holding a strong reference to `ParentView`, this creates a retain cycle and means neither of the controllers will be picked up by ARC and be deinitialized. So, if you are, for example, presenting `ParentView` from some other view and you keep going to `ParentView` and back, you will keep spawning new instances of `ParentView` (and `HashtagPicker`) with old ones still occupying memory.

Now, how this should have been done. I'll use exactly the same names as in the accepted answer.

The protocol should be defined like so:

```
// note the ": class" part
protocol HashTagPickerDelegate: class {
  func picked(hashtag: String)
}
```

If we specify `class`, it means the protocol can only be used on classes. This will allow use to create weak reference, which otherwise would have been impossible.

```
class HashtagPicker: UIViewController {
  // if HashTagPickerDelegate wouldn't be limited to class, 
  // we couldn't have made a weak reference here!
  weak var delegate: HashTagPickerDelegate?

  // at some point, you call the delegate, it can be anywhere, this is just an example
  @IBAction func tappedHashtag(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.picked(hashtag: "bla")
  }
}
```

Now we have a weak reference to delegate, so there is not retain cycle and ARC can clean up everything nicely!

I'll throw in the rest of the code to have this as a complete answer:

```
class ParentView: UIViewController {
  func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // we are presenting the nested controller
    if segue.identifier == "SegueHastagPickerContainer",
       let destinationController = segue.destination as? HashtagPicker {
      destinationController.delegate = self
    } 
  }
}

extension ParentView: HashTagPickerDelegate {
  func picked(hashtag: String) {
    // we just got info from the child controller, do something with it!
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a memory leak proof version, i changed the accepted answer because memory leaks is a problem i stumbled upon very late i think it needs to be more present for new devs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use delegates as mentioned in above answer. Or you can use notifications. So here is a solution using notifications.

First of all register a notification in your parent viewController's `viewDidLoad` like this

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ParentViewController.someActionToBePerformed), name: "myNotification", object: nil)
```

Create a function in your parent viewController named same as above so it will be like

```
func someActionToBePerformed () {
    // this will be called when hashTag is changed
    // do something when hashTag is changed 
}
```

Now you can simply post notification from your Hashtag `viewController`. When you want like this.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "myNotification"), object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (no notification, no delegate)

```
 func exitButtonTapped() {
    if let pdfVC : YourParnetViewController = self.parent as? YourParnetViewController {
        pdfVC.removeBlurEffect()
        self.removeFromParentViewController()
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```